# Can anyone recommend some good textbooks on measure theory and integration theory?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, book-recommendation

Currently I'm using J.Yeh's real analysis as a textbook but I find that this book is so chunky that I am often lost in the detail of the proofs of various theorems and hence I can't grasp the big picture of the real analysis, can anyone recommend some good textbooks on measure and integration theory?and I also hope that the book contains the theory of differentiation. thank you in advance

Comment: see [here](https://measure.axler.net/)

Comment: @Masacroso this book seems great and the only little flaw is that this book didn't cover the concept of converge in measure, and this book is also new, I like this book. and by the way where did you find this book?

Comment: I like this one: https://books.google.ch/books/about/Measure_and_Integral.html?id=YDkDmQ_hdmcC&redir_esc=y

Comment: @Yuer yah, I see... The book of Donald Cohn covers a lot more about measures, specially about differentiation of measures, but maybe it could be an overkill. What I didn't liked too much of the book of Cohn is that the topological concepts are not as well developed and presented than in many other books.

Comment: Rudin's RCA is very nice (I liked it much more than the first book 'Baby Rudin'). Folland also has a real analysis book (I used both Folland and Rudin simultaneously, so some chapters I read Rudin carefully, while others I read Folland). Also, Folland has a slightly more informal book "A Guide to Advanced Real Analysis", which is mainly a summary of definitions and in some places it elaborates the ideas in a more "conversational" manner (to me it was more like a storybook rather than a textbook). The most important thing though is to solve as many problems as you can, can't emphasize it enough

Comment: A more advanced treatment - https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540345138

Comment: @d.k.o yeah... but Bogachev book is a treatise more than a textbook, it is 1100+ pages long!